# Addressing issues with Apache Spark application run in Client mode from Docker container

Tags: apache-spark, docker, client, mode

I'm trying to connect to Standalone Apache Spark cluster from a dockerized Apache Spark application using Client mode.

Driver gives the Spark Master and the Workers its address. When run inside a docker container it will use `some_docker_container_ip`. The docker address is not visible from outside so an application won't work.

Spark has `spark.driver.host` property. This property is passed to Master and Workers. My initial instinct was to pass host machine address in there so the cluster would address visible machine instead.

Unfortunately the `spark.driver.host` is also used to set up a server by Driver. Passing a host machine address in there will cause server startup errors because a docker container cannot bind ports under host machine host.

It seems like a lose-lose situation. I cannot use neither the host machine address nor the docker container address.

Ideally I would like to have two properties. The `spark.driver.host-to-bind-to` used to set up the driver server and the `spark.driver.host-for-master` which would be used by Master and Workers. Unfortunately it seems like I'm stuck with one property only.

Another approach would be to use `--net=host` when running a docker container. This approach has many disadvantages (e.g. other docker containers cannot get linked to a container with the `--net=host` on and must be exposed outside of the docker network) and I would like to avoid it.

Is there any way I could solve the driver-addressing problem without exposing the docker containers?

Comment: Related issue from Spark Jira - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4563

It might not be possible to solve my problem with Spark currently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is fixed in https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/15120

It will be part of Apache Spark 2.1 release